# Redis behavior with multiple concurrent programs doing read/del on the same hash key

Tags: concurrency, transactions, redis, jedis

I've a program (`program_1`) (Jedis-based) that writes to a Redis HASH (`KEY_1`) on a regular basis. I've another program (`program_2`) (separate JVM process) that executes periodically, and in a Redis transaction does the following:

```
        Transaction transaction = redis.multi();
        //get the current entity table
        Response<Map<String, String>> currentEntityTableResponse = transaction.hgetAll(KEY_1);
        transaction.del(KEY_1);
        transaction.exec();
```

My assumption is when program_2 has deleted the HASH (with KEY_1) the next time program_1 runs it will create the HASH again. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. [Redis is single threaded](https://redis.io/topics/latency#single-threaded-nature-of-redis) and [transactions block until they finish](https://redis.io/topics/transactions), so if program_2 starts, the hash KEY_1 will no longer exist when program1 runs again.

Comment: What about merges? Say two processes use the same key and hmset, process #1 writes a map with `key field1 value`, and process #2 `key field2 value`?

What would the set contain?