# Two Clients Accessing REDIS Simultaneously using redis-py

Tags: python, redis

I have two redis-py clients that are accessing REDIS at the same time. Both clients are running infinite loops. Both clients are also looking at the same hash. The problem is that it seems when I start the continuous hgetall loop, I can no longer hset that value.

The first client is doing continuous hgetall

```
while True:
    query = r.hgetall('myHash')
    for result in query:
        #do something with value1, value2
```

The second client is doing continuous hset. If I remove the second client and just manually hset a new value, I still cannot set a new value.

```
r.hset('myHash', 'value1', '23')
r.hset('myHash', 'value2', '17')
```

Is this because REDIS is single threaded and the client that is hgetall never releases the thread to allow an hset?

Comment: AFAIK, redis has its own queue that will run in order. You can have multiple clients connected to it, but it will run only 1 command at a time on its own side. What problems are you getting?

Comment: Can you run MONITOR against your Redis instance to see what commands are getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely, that is why you can't `hset` and `hgetall` on the same hash. [Here](https://redis.io/topics/latency#single-threaded-nature-of-redis) is the official documentation about single threaded nature. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274638/redis-behavior-with-multiple-concurrent-programs-doing-read-del-on-the-same-hash) is a related question explaining the same behavior. Further, if you are looking to implement parllelism on top of `redis`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489298/redis-is-single-threaded-then-how-does-it-do-concurrent-i-o) is a guide for that.